# Set default value to null when converting to double in c#

Tags: c#

I want to pass the null if the string is empty while converting from string to double. Can somebody help me with the syntax? As where I going wrong?
Current Syntax:

```
IngredientMinRange = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MinRange) ? Convert.ToDouble(MinRange) : null
```

Comment: double is value type you have to make it nullable if you want to assign null to it

Comment: It is nullable public double? IngredientMinRange { get; set; }  here is the defination.

Comment: this does not return nullable double: Convert.ToDouble(MinRange)

Comment: than can you show us which errors you're getting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `double` cannot be `null` since it's a value- and not a reference type. You could use a [`Nullable<double>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
double? ingredientMinRange = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MinRange))
    ingredientMinRange = Convert.ToDouble(MinRange);
```

If you later want the `double` value you can use the `HasValue` and `Value` properties:

```
if(ingredientMinRange.HasValue)
{
    double value = ingredientMinRange.Value;
}
```

[Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

---

If `IngredientMinRange` is already a `Double?`-property as commented you can assign the value either via `if`(as shown above) or in in one line, but then you have to cast the `null`:

```
IngredientMinRange = string.IsNullOrEmpty(MinRange) ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(MinRange);
```

Comment: would you rather use `Convert.ToDouble` instead of `TryParse` when you convert from a string? (just asking) is it faster or anything?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: no, i'd prefer `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`(if the input can be invalid). But OP used `Convert.ToDouble` so i've assumed that it is supposed to be valid. Maybe `Convert.ToDouble` comes in handy if the input is an `object` instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

to assign `null` to a double you have to use `Nullable<double>` or `double?`. Assign it with this method here:

```
decimal temp;
decimal? IngredientMinRange = decimal.TryParse(MinRange, out temp) ? temp : (decimal?)null;
```

then you can continue working with `IngredientMinRange`. You get the value with `IngredientMinRange.Value` or check if it's null with `IngredientMinRange.HasValue`

Answer (score 0):

If it MinRange is an object:

```
IngredientMinRange = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MinRange.ToString()) ? Convert.ToDouble(MinRange) : 0;
```